# I need to split a file with 10 headers into multiple file with 5 headers each from the main file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and I have file which has header id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q1,q1_a,q2,q2_a,q3,q3_a and I need to split the file into multiple files with the following headers using python dataframe id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q1,q1_a into q1.csv id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q2,q2_a into q2.csv id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q3,q2_a into q3.csv.Can you give me insights on how to achieve this with Python pandas and dataframe? TIA.I tired using dataframe but it give me same header for all the files
data_dict = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
print (df)
header ={'id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q1,q1_a']
df.to_csv('output.csv', columns=header, index=False)

I am getting the below error
KeyError: "None of [Index()], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: How the accepted answer solves your problem? I really don't understand.

Comment: @Corralien, that's the question I asked myself too, this is confusing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to select and store the columns you want into two new dataframes and then print/save to csv.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('input.csv') #original data

    df_1 = df[['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5']] #first 5 columns

    df_2 = df[['column6', 'column7', 'column8', 'column9', 'column10']] #second 5 columns

    df_1.to_csv('output_1.csv', index = False) #save first csv

    df_2.to_csv('output_2.csv', index = False) #save second csv
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use:

```
index_cols = df.columns[:5].tolist()
group_cols = df.columns[5:].str.split('_').str[0]

for name, subdf in df.set_index(index_cols).groupby(group_cols, axis=1):
    subdf.to_csv(f'{name}.csv')
```

Content of `q1.csv`:

```
id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q1,q1_a
D,B,C,A,D,2,2
A,C,B,D,D,9,4
B,C,C,B,D,3,4
A,B,D,B,D,2,3
D,D,C,B,D,9,7
B,B,B,A,C,6,1
D,D,A,C,C,3,4
A,A,A,D,D,7,7
B,C,B,D,A,5,1
B,C,A,A,D,8,8
```

Content of `q2.csv`:

```
id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q2,q2_a
D,B,C,A,D,9,1
A,C,B,D,D,5,7
B,C,C,B,D,4,2
A,B,D,B,D,7,6
D,D,C,B,D,3,9
B,B,B,A,C,5,4
D,D,A,C,C,8,4
A,A,A,D,D,8,4
B,C,B,D,A,3,6
B,C,A,A,D,5,4
```

Content of `q3.csv`:

```
id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q3,q3_a
D,B,C,A,D,2,1
A,C,B,D,D,6,3
B,C,C,B,D,4,8
A,B,D,B,D,1,1
D,D,C,B,D,8,3
B,B,B,A,C,7,5
D,D,A,C,C,3,8
A,A,A,D,D,3,3
B,C,B,D,A,7,2
B,C,A,A,D,2,8
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
  id1 id2 id3 id4 id5  q1  q1_a  q2  q2_a  q3  q3_a
0   D   B   C   A   D   2     2   9     1   2     1
1   A   C   B   D   D   9     4   5     7   6     3
2   B   C   C   B   D   3     4   4     2   4     8
3   A   B   D   B   D   2     3   7     6   1     1
4   D   D   C   B   D   9     7   3     9   8     3
5   B   B   B   A   C   6     1   5     4   7     5
6   D   D   A   C   C   3     4   8     4   3     8
7   A   A   A   D   D   7     7   8     4   3     3
8   B   C   B   D   A   5     1   3     6   7     2
9   B   C   A   A   D   8     8   5     4   2     8
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using [*Index*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) operations :

```
ids = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith("id")]
qas = df.columns.difference(ids)

for i in range(0, len(qas), 2):
    df[ids.union(qas[i:i+2])].to_csv(f"out/{qas[i]}.csv", index=False)
```

Output :

```
out
┣━━ q1.csv # id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q1,q1_a
┣━━ q2.csv # id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q2,q2_a
┗━━ q3.csv # id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,q3,q3_a
```

Input used :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5",
             "q1", "q1_a", "q2", "q2_a", "q3", "q3_a"]
)
```